# Using variables from another page

Tags: c#, variables, uwp

I have two pages, these are called "page1.xaml.cs" and "page2.xaml.cs"

In page1, I have variable like this;

```
public string var1="hello world";
```

In page2, I have a button, and whenever I click that button, it should bring "var1" from page1.

I can't use "Frame.Navigate(typeof" function because I need to use that value whenever I need it.

So how can I use that variable from another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a variable defined in a specific page from another page, you should simply define that variable as *static*.

```
public static string var1 = "hello world";
```

Now you can easily access it's content, like this : `page1.var1`

Variables declared as static are commonly shared across all instances of a class, and this way when you navigate onto the `Page2`, you will not be required to still hold a reference to the instance of the `Page1` that you just navigated from.

And, since it seems your intention for your string variable is for it to have the same content despite the different instantiations that will occur to your `Page1` class during your application execution, it would be a completely waste to not mark it as `static`!

Comment: Oh thank you! finally I found it. I knew that it was something that easy but i forgot it. Love you <3

Comment: By the way, is there a way to control xaml file as well? for example, can i make an item enabled from different cs file? like in page2.xaml.cs, control page1.xaml element?